# Upload file to S3 but return observable

Tags: angular, amazon-s3, file-upload

How would I ensure that the following method returns an observable?

```
  uploadFile(file, filename) {
    const contentType = file.type;
    const bucket = new S3(
      {
        accessKeyId: environment.awsAccessKeyId,
        secretAccessKey: environment.awssecretAccessKey,
        region: environment.awsRegion
      }
    );
    const params = {
      Bucket: environment.awsBucket,
      Key: environment.awsKey + filename,
      Body: file,
      ACL: 'public-read',
      ContentType: contentType
    };

    bucket.upload(params, function (err, data) {
      if (err) {
        this.logger.debug('There was an error uploading your file: ', err);
        return null;
      }
      this.logger.debug('Successfully uploaded file.', data);
      return data;
    });
  }
```

I'd like to call it from an component as follows and capture the return output:

```
  this.ngxLoader.start();
  this.uploadService.uploadFile(newFile, sermonName), ((data) => {
    if (data) {
      // this.sermon.id = data.id;
      // this.logger.debug(`Posted file: ${JSON.stringify(data)}`);
      // this.logger.debug(`Updating file id: ${JSON.stringify(this.sermon.id)}`);
      // this.update();
      this.ngxLoader.stop();
    }
  }, error => {
    this.ngxLoader.stop();
    this.modalService.displayMessage('Oops!', error.message);
  });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Changes to return the result/error as Observable

```
return Observable.create(observer => {
  bucket.upload(params, function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      this.logger.debug('There was an error uploading your file: ', err);
      observer.error(err);
    }
    this.logger.debug('Successfully uploaded file.', data);
    observer.next(data);
    observer.complete();
  });
});
```

Changes to handle result/error in component

```
this.uploadService.uploadFile(newFile, sermonName)
.subscribe(
  data => {
    if (data) {
      // this.sermon.id = data.id;
      // this.logger.debug(`Posted file: ${JSON.stringify(data)}`);
      // this.logger.debug(`Updating file id: ${JSON.stringify(this.sermon.id)}`);
      // this.update();
      this.ngxLoader.stop();
    }
  }, 
  error => {
    this.ngxLoader.stop();
    this.modalService.displayMessage('Oops!', error.message);
  });
```

of course we need to import the below.

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
```

also add the explicit return for the function for type checking.

```
uploadFile(file, filename): Observable<any> {
```